# SQL Server Dates and TimeZone confusion

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, timezone

I've got some major confusion when trying to deal with timestamps on servers in multiple timezones.

We have two SQL Servers (Alpha and Beta) in UTC+12 and UTC-6 respectively with records that are synchronized daily.  Our problem is that if a record is updated with a timestamp in Alpha and synchronized to Beta, the Beta time appears to have the exact time (in local time) as the Alpha local time rather than UTC.

I know there are a lot of potential pitfalls, but it appears that both servers have the same binary representation of the timestamp, so the real question is **"Have we misconfigured SQL Server somehow?  Or does the synchronization software need to convert the binary date?"**

First of all executing

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE()
SELECT GETDATE()
```

on both servers gives the same date/time for UTC and correct local time, so they are configured in their proper timezones.

Defining `df` as the date column

```
SELECT df FROM tbl

Result
-------------------
2014-10-29 00:49:57.870
```

in both environments gives the same human readable string

Further that, selecting the underlying binary data from the field on both systems gives the same value:

```
select cast(df as binary(8)) 
from tbl

Result
------------------
0x0000A3D3000DB921
```

This tells me that the internal representation of the two dates is the same. From the docs, I understand this to be:

- First 4 bytes - number of days since Jan 1, 1900
- Second 4 bytes - clock ticks since midnight

Perhaps I misunderstood this... I assumed it was days offset in UTC, maybe it's days offset in local time? Which would mean the underlying binary data is stored in local time? But I don't think this is right.

However, the two dates are very clearly not being treated as the same. Updating the column at Alpha with the current time puts in the proper timestamp, then the two sites sync and Beta has the same underlying binary value, but running the initial select (`SELECT df FROM tbl`) gives a time nearly 18 hours in the future...

Attempting to convert the time to UTC also gives different times:

```
select 
    df, 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), df) 
from tbl
```

- Result on Alpha - 2014-10-28 11:49:57.870  (The correct UTC time)
- Result on Beta  - 2014-10-29 06:49:57.870

I appreciate you sticking with me for this long. Time zones are trickier than Run DMC.

So summary, I suppose:

- What's the preferred way to synchronize absolute (UTC) time between databases in different time zones?
- What does the binary representation of a SQL Server datestamp actually mean? (I know that should be answerable from the help docs, but I can't find the correct ones)

Comment: The preferred way? Have all your servers set to UTC (or, less reliably, always populate with GETUTCDATE() instead of GETDATE()). Convert to local time on the way out.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means though...  we're storing 0x0000A3D3000DB921, right? Does this binary string actually have different meaning based on the server's time zone?  I would find that to be odd, but if that's the case then so be it.
Or do I fundamentally misunderstand what's happening?

Comment: I'm not following your logic at all,. You say that on *both servers* you have stored `2014-10-29 00:49:57.870`, yes? Why is it a surprise that if you convert to binary, the output is the same on both servers? The input is the same, so I'm not sure why you would expect anything different. The reason you get different times when converting this *same value* to UTC is because the two servers are in different time zones. You didn't store the same date/time in both servers; you stored it correctly in one server, but on the other you stored it in the wrong time zone.

Comment: What on earth is "the synchronization software" anyway?

Comment: In this case we're using a product called SRO to sync multiple databases (http://www.srosolutions.net/).  

It sounds like what you're saying is that I simply misunderstood the way date-times are stored in SQL Server.  I thought the binary value was an absolute timestamp independent of other settings on the server.  (e.g., milliseconds since epoch in UTC).  It sounds like you're saying that the stored time is relative which was just unintuitive for me.

Comment: No, the binary value is a representation of the actual datetime value you stored. If you say Jan 1st at 9 PM, it stores Jan 1st at 9 PM. It doesn't give a crap about epoch or UTC or any of that.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion.  Post this stuff as an answer if you'd like and I can accept it.  I'm still baffled that the timezone isn't part of the timestamp, I guess I was just plain wrong in my assumption there.

Comment: I know this post is old but I find the interesting thing is the value in select is 18 hours in the future and it sounds like A is Subtracting the time zone of B  UTC+12 - UTC-6 becomes UTC +18.